# Error in domain [odoo 8 ]

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have a model named 'A' it has a many2one relation (a) with another model 'B'  and another relation one2many with a model 'C'. In 'C' there is a many2one field 'c'. In 'B' i have a one2many field 'b'. I want to set a domain for the field 'c' like this:
domain="[('id','in',parent.a.b)]" , i've put this on the xml view but i got the following javascript error :
Uncaught Error: AttributeError: object has no attribute 'b' ...
http://localhost:8069/web/static/lib/py.js/lib/py.js:757
...and i don't know how to set this domain using python code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client side, such as webclient views, you can't use "dot notation" to access related field values.
That is only possible in server side domains, such as the ones used by Record Rules.

The be able to do what you want, you need to create a `Related` field that makes the `parent.a.b` value available for the Model's views.